# Lookahead updating a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
someList = [{'a':3}, {'a':4}, {'a':6}]
```

Assuming that the length of `someList` is >1000 , what is the most efficient and pythonic way to obtain the following list of dictionaries:

```
someList = [{'prev_a':0, 'a': 3 , 'next_a': 4}, {'prev_a':3, 'a':4 , 'next_a' : 6}, {'prev_a':4, 'a': 6 , 'next_a': 0}]
```

Where:

- `next_a` has the value of a in the succeeding dictionary and
- `prev_a` has the value of a in the preceding dictionary
- first and last values for prev_a and next_a, respectively, can be 0

### Update 1:

The number of variables, such as `a` can be more than one; the dictionary could look like this:

```
someList = [{'a':2,'b':4,'c':9}]
dict_key_values = ['a','c']
```

In this case the list I want to get should only feature the `prev_` and `next_` values of `a` and `c`

```
someList = [{'prev_a':4, 'a': 6 , 'next_a': 0, 'prev_c':4, 'c': 3 , 'next_c': 0, 'b':1}, ...]
```

(Without the use of Pandas)

#### Edit

My initial approach was to `enumerate(someList)`, use `someList[i-1]['a']`and `someList[i+1]['a']` to access the element before and after to get prev_a and next_a.

The problem with this approach is that when the number of variables such as `a` increase, the code becomes hard to manage

Comment: By efficient, do you mean time-efficient or space-efficient?

Comment: preferably both but prioritising time efficiency

Comment: Another question: by the look of what you are trying to achieve, have you considered implementing it using a doubly linked list instead?

Comment: It seems like this should be straightforward using `enumerate(someList)` You can use `someList[i-1]['a']` and `someList[i+1]['a']` to access the element before and after to get `prev_a` and `next_a`.

Comment: I haven't . Would you consider it to be an efficient approach for this problem?

Comment: @Barmar I have tried that. Sorry let me quickly add it to the question. The problem with that is that the code is not concise and hard to manage (considering the number of variables like `a` would increase)

Comment: does your list contain only `{'a':3}` or more different elements?

Comment: Can contain more different elements. Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools` to get multiple iterators over the same list. Then it only has to take up memory for the current elements. You can use `islice` to skip one, and `chain` to prepend one. Then zip them together into triples to iterate over all three offsets at once.

If you like, you can use a comprehension to build the triples into dicts. (But depending on your use case, it might be more time-efficient to skip this step and use the triples directly.)

```
from itertools import chain, islice, zip_longest

def lookahead(someList, dict_key_values):
    filldict = dict.fromkeys(dict_key_values, 0)
    prefixes = ["prev_", "next_"]
    return [
        {prefix+k: v
         for prefix, d in zip(prefixes, [p, n])
         for k, v in d.items() if k in filldict}
        | c
        for p, c, n in
        zip_longest(
            chain([filldict], someList),
            someList,
            islice(someList, 1, None),
            fillvalue=filldict,
        )
    ]
```

The `zip_longest` will fill in extra values after the iterators are exhausted up till the longest one.

```
>>> someList = [{'a':2,'b':4,'c':9}]
>>> dict_key_values = ['a','c']
>>> lookahead(someList, dict_key_values)
[{'prev_a': 0, 'prev_c': 0, 'next_a': 0, 'next_c': 0, 'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 9}, {'prev_a': 2, 'prev_c': 9, 'next_a': 0, 'next_c': 0, 'a': 0, 'c': 0}]
```

If you prefer to stop at the shortest one (the `islice` in this case), use the builtin `zip` instead (and omit the `fillvalue`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are planning to access the content of the list, i would think an implementaiton of a doubly linked list would be a good option. With that, the content of each Node would be independent from the links between the nodes, enabling you to alter attributes of a Node without having to change the logic when creating the list itself.

an example here:
https://realpython.com/linked-lists-python/#how-to-use-doubly-linked-lists